# How do you sort an array of objects by key pair values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How would I sort an array of objects using the values in the desiredOrder array?
I want my array objects to be sorted by the **type** key in each object. I want all the *fruit* items to show first, then the *drug* items, then the *wheat* items. Etc. It would be preferred if the function was a reusable one.

```js
// This is the order I want myList sorted in by the object property type
let desiredOrder = ['fruit', 'drugs', 'wheat', 'candy', 'vegetable', 'dairy']



// Here is my list of objects
let myList = [
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "apple"
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "carrot"
    },
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "orange"
    },
    {
        type: "dairy",
        subType: "milk"
    },
    {
        type: "wheat",
        subType: "bread"
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "lettuce"
    },
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "mango"
    },
    {
        type: "drugs",
        subType: 'cocaine'
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "spinach"
    },
    {
        type: "candy",
        subType: "chocolate"
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "celery"
    },
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "pineapple"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The function

`(a, b) => (desiredOrder.indexOf(a.type) - desiredOrder.indexOf(b.type)) || (a.subType > b.subType ? 1 : -1) || 0;`

Will order first on the order the type is in the array and then by the subType if they have the same type.

```js
let desiredOrder = ['fruit', 'drugs', 'wheat', 'candy', 'vegetable', 'dairy']



// Here is my list of objects
let myList = [
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "apple"
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "carrot"
    },
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "orange"
    },
    {
        type: "dairy",
        subType: "milk"
    },
    {
        type: "wheat",
        subType: "bread"
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "lettuce"
    },
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "mango"
    },
    {
        type: "drugs",
        subType: 'cocaine'
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "spinach"
    },
    {
        type: "candy",
        subType: "chocolate"
    },
    {
        type: "vegetable",
        subType: "celery"
    },
    {
        type: "fruit",
        subType: "pineapple"
    },
];

const compareTypeThenSubtype = (a, b) => (desiredOrder.indexOf(a.type) - desiredOrder.indexOf(b.type)) || (a.subType > b.subType ? 1 : -1) || 0;

myList.sort(compareTypeThenSubtype);

console.log(myList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
myList.sort((preItem, nextItem) =>
  desiredOrder.indexOf(preItem.type) > desiredOrder.indexOf(nextItem.type) ? 1 : -1
);
```